# use email address as datastore key using python app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I define my model `ndb` in python. I want to use the email address of a user as the key, how do I do that? user is passing in the email address through an html form. I have everything setup and working. I just don't know how to specify that the email address string is the key.

Comment: don't forget users can change their email address ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your entity do this:

MyModel(id=emailAddress).put()

then use get_by_id

user = MyModel.get_by_id(emailAddress)